# C: "?:" operator expression equivalency

Tags: c

A few days ago i wrote a function that'd receive an int n greater than 0 and return the nth prime number. I wondered how much shorter that could be wrote and i came up with this:

```
int f(int i){int n=2,d=2,j=1;for(j;j<i;j+=n==d)n%d<1?n++,d=2:d++;return n;}
```

Then i saw the n%d<1 in the for and thought why not change it with just n%d and invert the order of the "?:" operator expressions, like this:

```
int g(int i){int n=2,d=2,j=1;for(j;j<i;j+=n==d)n%d?d++:n++,d=2;return n;}
```

But it just doesn't work, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. The d=2 never actually happens, i think. Can anyone point me out why not or what to read to figure it out?

If it's of any help, i'm running Ubuntu and compiling with gcc -std=c99 only.

Comment: `for(j;` doesn't do anything. You can remove the `j` (I bet `-Wall` would have told you about this).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: What does the `j+=n==d` part do in the for loop? If `+=` occurs first, then the equality test seems pointless. If `n==d` evaluates first then surely this is adding either `true` or `false` - is that adding `1` or `0`?

Comment: @melpomene Why not put the `int j = 1` in that part of the for loop?

Comment: Also why `n%d<1` not `n%d==0`?

Comment: Exactly, it adds 1 when that expression is true or 0 otherwise. So that it counts how many prime numbers it has found so far.

Comment: @user3728501 That makes the code longer.

Comment: @user3728501 not using int j=1 inside the loop to save characters, writing it shorter, same goes for your second question (only 1 char saved there)

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realize the point was to minimize character usage. Seems like an odd question to ask on here.

Comment: @CrossNox is this also why you make use of the comma operator rather than using {} braces and semicolons to separate statements?

Comment: @user3728501 Inside the ?: i didn't use semicolons because it's an expression that is evaluated, that's why the comma. Actually i never thought of using braces. But still, yes, it saves some chars with the comma.

Comment: @CrossNox so there's no way to invert the tertiary operator without going back to 75 chars or more. BTW you can avoid using j since it does nothing but break the loop if it reaches i, so you can just decrease i instead. Try: `int h(int i){int n=2,d=2;for(;i-=n==d;)n%d<1?n++,d=2:d++;return n;}//67 chars`.

Comment: @Emisor that one works as well. The j thing had already been pointed out, but putting the decreasing in the second for parameter is genius... actually, i had no idea that could be done (rather never would have figured it out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue of operator precedence. `?:` has higher precedence than `,`, so

```
A , B ? C : D , E
```

parses as

```
A , (B ? C : D) , E
```

However, this doesn't apply to the middle part of `?:` which works like it's surrounded by parens (because in a sense `?` ... `:` is a bracketing construct):

```
A ? B , C : D
```

parses as

```
A ? (B , C) : D
```

because that's the only thing it can do without being a syntax error.

---

You can fix this by adding explicit parens:

```
n%d?d++:(n++,d=2);
```

Comment: So if i were to put it between brackets it would work?

Comment: Add that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

The ternary `?:` operator has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the comma.  Thus,

```
n%d?d++:n++,d=2
```

gets parsed as:

```
(n % d ? d++ : n++), d = 2
```

which is not what you want.

The reason it works in your first example is because there the comma is *between* the `?` and the `:`, which act as paired delimiters just like parentheses, curly braces and square brackets do.